# createElement and appendChild in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild, createelement

I am trying to figure out why the createElement and appendChild aren't working. I believe I've got my code correct so I'm not too sure why it's not working... (I am using IE 10)

**CODE UPDATED**

JavaScript File:

```
var myObj = {

   firstName: "John",
   lastName: "Smith"
};
```

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html>
<title>The Data Structure</title>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="TheData.js">

var theElement = document.createElement('p');
var theText = document.createTextNode(myObj.firstName);
theElement.appendChild(theText);
document.body.appendChild(theElement);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you *both* supply a `src` on your `script` tag *and* provide content within it. That's invalid, you can do one or the other, not both. Most browsers will use the `src` and disregard the content.

Separate from that, creating an element doesn't put it in the DOM. You have to add it somewhere (via `appendChild` or `insertBefore` or similar).

So perhaps:

```
<script src="TheData.js"></script>
<!-- Note: Two separate script elements -->
<script>
var theElement = document.createElement('p');
var theText = document.createTextNode(myObj.firstName);
theElement.appendChild(theText);
document.body.appendChild(theElement); // <==== Note: Adding `the Element` to the DOM
</script>
```

Comment: A small detail noted by Crazy Train: it should be `myObj.firstName` (lowercase `f`) in the line that creates the text node.

Answer (score 2):

You never append `theElement` to the document! Add one more line at the end:

```
document.body.appendChild(theElement);
```

---

As a side note, what's this immediately invoked function for?

```
(function () {
return myObj.firstName;
}());
```

It does nothing!

Comment: Yea that anonymous function will turn into something. Just a placeholder for now. Kind of one of those things I started on but didn't finish.

Comment: Also, `myObj.FirstName !== myObj.firstName`